# how to fix error while running npm install

Tags: angular, linux

when running npm install on terminal of vs code i get this error . I did some research on the errors and it seems that maybe some of the packages being installed have some conflicts. How can i fix it is it problem of update ?

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/abir_mabrouk/Desktop/My-University-master/my-univ-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.13.0-41-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/abir_mabrouk/Desktop/My-University-master/my-univ-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/abir_mabrouk/Desktop/My-University-master/my-univ-frontend/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.22.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
```

and this is the second error

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/abir_mabrouk/.npm/_logs/2022-05-15T09_41_24_646Z-debug.log
```

and this the package.json

```
{
  "name": "ngx-admin",
  "version": "3.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "IE 11"
  ],
  
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "node your-script.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint ngx-admin-demo --fix",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:ci",
    "release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.3",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "3.0.1",
    "@nebular/auth": "3.1.0",
    "@nebular/bootstrap": "3.1.0",
    "@nebular/security": "3.1.0",
    "@nebular/theme": "3.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^10.0.0",
    "angular-tree-component": "7.2.0",
    "angular2-chartjs": "0.4.1",
    "angular2-toaster": "^6.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "chart.js": "2.7.1",
    "ckeditor": "4.7.3",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "echarts": "^4.0.2",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.1",
    "leaflet": "1.2.0",
    "nebular-icons": "1.1.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-completer": "2.0.8",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.3.5",
    "ngx-echarts": "^4.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "6.3.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "tinymce": "4.5.7",
    "typeface-exo": "0.0.22",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.10.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.0.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/d3-color": "1.0.5",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.2.3",
    "@types/node": "6.0.90",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "1.3.4",
    "gulp-coffee": "^3.0.3",
    "husky": "0.13.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "stylelint": "7.13.0",
    "ts-node": "3.2.2",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9",
    "typescript": "3.1.3"
  }
}
```

is it a problem of version of some packages ?

Comment: You might want to upgrade your node version to at least version 14..

Answer (score 0):

The similar problem I had faced in macOS

This problem is due to `node-sass`.

I have fixed with re-install it again by `npm i node-sass`

Finally, then I can able to install packages by `npm i`

I hope this solution will worked for you